# What would the correct syntax be for this 301 with a query string in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have several url's built like this:

> /news/report_detail.asp?id=100&edition=14

I'd like to add a rewrite in .htaccess, so they look like this:

> report-detail-asp-id-100-edition-14

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: When you say "so they look like this," you are not referring to within the user's address bar, are you?

Comment: Kenneth: Yes, I am. I just need to come up with the regex that's going to take that query string, so I can redirect to /news/report-detail-asp-id-whatever#-edition-whatever#. My cms system is creating the cleaner aliases already, I just need to take the 1500 or so url's and redirect them.

Comment: Forgive me, but my understanding of URL rewriting is that you turn clean into ugly, not the other way around. You (or your CMS) would be outputting the clean URLs to the user (i.e. the web page rendered on the user's system), and when the user clicks a "clean" link, the rewrite engine intercepts the request, and it translates the clean link into an ugly link--what the server expects. Are we still talking about the same thing?

Comment: Hey Ken, no not exactly. My dilemna is I have 1500 url's or so, that are written in the "ugly" format with the query string. I'm having to use those as titles in my CMS (I'm not going to redo 1500 links). So all I'd like to do is somehow come up with the regex that will clean up the query and redirect to the "clean" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&edition=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule news/report_detail.asp news/report-detail-asp-id-%1-edition-%2? [R=301,L]
```

Note that I am making an assumption that this is in your root folder's .htaccess file and you have a RewriteBase / directive already, and that you left off `news/` from the beginning of the redirection URL above. Otherwise you may need to make some tweaks to this code. But this will take the user from `/news/report_detail.asp?id=100&edition=14` to `/news/report-detail-asp-id-100-edition-14`

Comment: Wige..thanks much..this is handling the redirect. How would I change the above to this: /news/report-detail-100-edition-14? Just leave out the -asp part in the 2nd line?

Comment: Or, what about this url: /news/report_edition.asp?id=59? Rewriting to this: report-edition-asp-id-59 would work.

Comment: Christopher, to the first question, yes. To the second, I would simply create a second set of rules to handle the cases where no edition is specified.

Comment: Thanks Wige, I ended up getting it all going w/your help..I appreciate it.